# How to Install imagemagick 8-bit depth with homebrew

Tags: macos, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm using Mac Lion with RVM, homebrew and bundler and the rmagick gem

When I execute the following command:

```
brew install imagemagick

convert --version
```

the imagemagick version that is installed is Q16 (16-bit depth) , but I prefer the 8-bit depth version for speed reasons.

what is the correct brew command to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised homebrew formula's are just ruby scripts, so searched for the imagemagick formula.

```
locate imagemagick.rb
```

So you can see all the available options in the options method in:

```
/usr/local/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
```

So in the end, it was just a simple

```
brew install imagemagick --with-quantum-depth-8
```

See also [homebrew install imagemagick 8 bit version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923126/homebrew-install-imagemagick-8-bit-version/11924228#11924228)

## UPDATE for brew 2

Brew version 2 does not allow additional compile (`./configure`) settings anymore. You now have to edit the fromula yourself and recompile.

Open and edit the brew formula

```
brew edit imagemagick
```

Add the following line under the `args = %W[` section

```
--with-quantum-depth=8
```

Then install and coile with `-s`

```
brew install imagemagick -s
```

Then test your new installation of ImageMagick with

```
convert --version
```

You will see the `Q8` on the first line after the version number.

P.S.
if you use rmagick, and just changed your ImageMagick, make sure you `gem uninstall rmagick && bundle install`