# homebrew install imagemagick 8 bit version

Tags: macos, imagemagick, homebrew, rmagick, osx-mountain-lion

I would like to install the 8-bit version of imagemagick using homebrew, as the performance is a little better and the RGB values outputted with the 8 bit version are better suited to my uses.

How would I got about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `brew install imagemagick --with-quantum-depth-8` should do the trick.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with MacPorts? I tried `sudo port install ImageMagick --with-quantum-depth-8` but got `Error: Port --with-quantum-depth-8 not found`